# In Windows XP, how can I permanently disable full screen command prompts?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, command-line, fullscreen

I have a program running that insists on running cmd.exe in full screen. Is there a way to disable this feature?

Comment: You did try [ALT]-[ENTER], right?

Comment: Of course. But that only gets me out of full screen.

Comment: @Christian Jonassen: What's the name of the program? It might have an option to open the command prompt in windowed mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you type do `Start>Run>cmd` and it opens in a regular box, the answer is almost certainly not. The program is calling the command box on its own, and in full-screen mode. You are not going to be able to change the program's code. I also know of no way to inhibit the cmd from running in full screen.

If do Start>Run>cmd and it opens in full screen, then it is something in your registry and we can attack that if you post back.

Comment: Start->Run->cmd gives me a regular box ...

Comment: That proves that it is programmatic and that short of somehow reverse engineering the software, changing the code, and re-compiling it, you will not be able to change it. I really doubt any other answer will manage to give you a successful outcome. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.

Comment: Note: Ctrl+space and setting properties worked for that particular application.

Comment: Where did you set that exactly? Also, was the whole program opening full screen, or just calling a cmd box within it (as I thought)?

Comment: This sounds like the program is opening the window at full screen.  You'll need to find a program that forces it to a certain size, which itself is difficult to write.

Comment: @KCotreau: Sorry for the extremely late reply, but: Ctrl+space gives the same menu that you get when you right-click on the upper left corner of the window. Then from there, properties.